# All memory go's to “Standby” and no memory left on “Free” issue (Win 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, virtual-memory, memory-leaks

[image]Problem on my win 8.1 the memory does not go's to free memory when another apps or game are on..it is causing my pc work extrimly slow even when it says 13GB available..what should i do? (All forms i rad, no answer was found)
More in that,When i launch BF4,the game does not run for a long,and im getting kick out due to lack of memory

file:///C:/Users/alex/Desktop/1.png

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. Free memory is wasted memory. “Standby” is data no longer referenced, so-called cached data. It can become active again with minimal delay. This includes file data, executable images and various other stuff.

It will be displaced, also with minimal delay, when an application requires more memory.

If you truly think you have a memory issue, please get [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229). Then, update your question to include a screenshot of its main view.

Comment: I have no "Points" to update an image on my post

Comment: You can always use some image host and link it. I'll embed it later.